# What is the best way to handle sate in React component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the best way to handle state in React functional components? using a single object like:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState ({
  email:example@example.com,
  name:"tesName"
})
```

or should I use `useState` for each state variable

```js
const [email, setEmail] = useState("example@example.com,")
const [name, setName] = useState("tesName")
```

tried both methods. just wanted to know which one is better and why?

Comment: First you'd need a complete and unambiguous definition of "better".  I imagine this is entirely opinion-based and subjective to any given component.

Comment: @David In dev, better is usually related to performance isn't?

Comment: @Hatana: [Define "performance"](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @David this is a good article tbh i like it, however, here, in the context of the question, "better" should mean which one avoids unnecessary renders because other than that, all other factors are negligible but I agree the op could clarify more

Comment: @Hatana: Maybe, maybe not.  The code shown provides no context whatsoever.  What if the re-rendering is relatively trivial and well within runtime performance tolerances, but the overall state object is complex with multiple levels of depth?  What if the state object has dynamic/recursive depth and it's not statically known how many "variables" it contains?  What if dissecting the object into separate state values itself incurs a performance cost?  Or development cost?  Or memory cost?  We can't really assume any of this.  The message of "always focus on fewer re-renders" is short-sighted.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this example](https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-mclaren-yp45nk?file=/src/App.js):

```js
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component rerender!") 
  })
  const [myState, setMyState] = useState({
    name: "ahmed",
    isAdmin: "false"
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => {
        setMyState(prev => {
          return {
            ...prev,
            isAdmin: true
          }
        })
      }}>Make it admin</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you will see each time you set `isAdmin` to `true` the component rerenders, this makes sense since the state is an object so it does not matter if it is set to the exact same previous value, it will always be treated like it got a new completely different value. therefore the component rerenders.
however, if you make each property of your object `useState` hook like in this example

```js
export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("component rerender!");
  });
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [isAdmin, setIsAdmin] = useState();
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setIsAdmin(true);
        }}
      >
        Make it admin
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you won't face that since `isAdmin` is `boolean` now and React can easily detect if its new value is different from the old one using `Object.is`.

Answer (score -1):

In React functional components, the most recommended way to handle state is by using the useState hook for each state variable. While using a single object like const `state = { email: 'example@example.com', name: 'testName' };` might seem convenient at first, it can lead to potential issues and is generally not considered a best practice. Here's why:

1. Immutability: React relies on immutability to efficiently determine when to re-render components. When you use the `useState` hook, React knows that a specific state variable has changed, and it can update only the relevant parts of the component tree. If you use a single object to hold multiple state variables, changing one property of the object would mutate the object, and React might not detect the change correctly, leading to unexpected behavior and bugs.
2. Performance: Using separate `useState` hooks for each state variable allows React to optimize re-renders. When you update a state using `useState`, React can keep track of the individual states' changes. In contrast, when using a single object for multiple state variables, each state update would require the entire object to be recreated, leading to potential performance bottlenecks, especially in large and complex components.

So, it's generally recommended to use the `useState` hook for each state variable:

````
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('example@example.com');
  const [name, setName] = useState('testName');

  // Use the individual state variables (email and name) in your component logic here

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your JSX goes here */}
    </div>
  );
};```

Following this approach, you'll have cleaner, more efficient, and maintainable code that aligns with React's best practices for handling state in functional components.
````

Comment: looks like chatGPT